# Explicity disable image sharing to facebook using mini_fb gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems

I use `mini_fb` to share text and images to facebook. My requirement is

- When share text then it should share only text
- When share text with image, then both text and image should be shared.

My problem is when I share text only, then a random image from the url is posted to facebook along with text. When I searched for it, I found that facebook is picking up images with og:image tag, and picking the last image and posted it.

But there is no explicit meta tag with property `"og:image"` in my site.

To avoid this I also put explicit meta tag with property `"og:image"`. But the client does not need this.

Can I explicity disable image sharing to facebook, when no image is shared to facebook using 'mini_fb' gem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that at the moment it isn't possible, not because of the gem, but because of facebook.

> By removing the ability to customize link metadata (i.e. headline, description, image) from all link sharing entry points on Facebook, we are eliminating a channel that has been abused to post false news.

you can see more information about this here

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/

the way you solved it at the moment is the right way. it's better for you to set explicit the image you want to show, so there is more control about it by you.